# How to check a view in fragment is appearing in the current window or it's out of the current window?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-scrollview

I have a scroll view and text view inside it, I want to know whether it's gone out of the window or it's still inside the window.

```
scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
                    L.e(" isShown " + textView.isShown());
                }
            });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below code. it's perfectly working for me

```
if (scrollView != null) {
       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
           Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
           scrollView.getHitRect(scrollBounds);
           scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
               @Override
               public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
                   String title = "your title";
                   if (view != null) {
                       if (view.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)) {
                           setPageTitle("");
                       } else {
                           setPageTitle(title == null ? "" : title);
                       }
                   }
               }
           });
       }
   }
```